# Find the sum of the factorial of each digit of a number using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I need to find the sum of the factorial of each digit of a number using recursion.

Doing this iteratively would be relatively simple, but I am supposed to do it recursively.

I haven't gotten a solution yet. I have only gotten small pieces of this problem.

**Method to find factorial**

```
public static int factorial(int n) {

    if (n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

**Method to find sum of digits**

```
public static int sum_of_digit(int n) {
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
     }
    return (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10));
}
```

My issue is trying to use what I know to now get the factorial of each digit and add those together.

**EDIT:** (provided by author from comments):

Example

```
n=145 1! = 1 4! = 24 5!=120 (sum = 1 + 24 + 120)
```

Comment: the logic would go as such
n=145

1! = 1

4! = 24

5!=120

                                                           (sum = 1 + 24 + 120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to do.  I renamed your sum method to illustrate its purpose.

```
int v = sum_of_digit_factorials(325);
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
128
```

The methods

```
// the original factorial method
public static int factorial(int n) {

    if (n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
// the modified sum method.
public static int sum_of_digit_factorials(int n) {
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
     }
    return  factorial(n%10) + sum_of_digit_factorials(n/10);
}
```

As the method is called, factorial computes the factorial of the each digit in succession, starting with the right most digit.  At this point, any previous calls to `sum_of_digit_factorials` have not returned. When `n` reaches  zero, the calls to the sum method will unwind (return), summing up the returned factorials that were computed and stored on the stack, eventually returning the final sum.

The key to thinking about this is that the call stack stores local values on the stack and then as the method is returned, those local values are recovered and acted upon. Recursive programming has its advantages.  But because it involves repetitive method calls it is not efficient.  And because the call stack is finite (but large), it can overflow due to unrestrained method calls.

I also recommend placing print statements in the sum method.  You can even break up the last return statement into two parts.  By printing n and the computed factorials, it will help to see how this produces the answer.

I have put in the following code and its output to show what is happening.  Only the summing method has print statements.

```
public static int sum_of_digit_factorials(int n) {
    System.out.println("sum_of_digit_factorials entered: n = " + n);
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int k = n % 10;
    int f = factorial(k);
    System.out.println(k + " factorial = " + f);
    int sum = sum_of_digit_factorials(n / 10);
    sum += f;
    System.out.println("current sum = " + sum);
    return sum;        
}
```

prints

```
sum_of_digit_factorials entered: n = 325
5 factorial = 120
sum_of_digit_factorials entered: n = 32
2 factorial = 2
sum_of_digit_factorials entered: n = 3
3 factorial = 6
sum_of_digit_factorials entered: n = 0  // this triggers the return and the
                                        // summing process begins.
current sum = 6
current sum = 8
current sum = 128
128                                     // the final result, printed in main
```

Comment: Thanks, Works. I'm quite new to recursive, if you can, could you write a break down of the logic of the recursive calls. like a step by step of each of the calls. I don't want to just copy paste answers. I really want to understand. By the way, i understand the factorial method, i dont understand the sum_of_digit_factorials method

Comment: See my modified answer for an explanation.

Comment: I added more information.  I  recommend you delete your comment with code as it is hard to read (and putting lots of code in comments is frowned upon in SO).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sum_of_digit(int n) {
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10));
}
```

In the above method, the part `n % 10` is calculating the remainder after dividing n by 10, for example `32 % 10 = 2`.

Then its adding that `2` to the tail calculation, using `n / 10` as input. in the same example `32 / 10 = 3`.

The result of the example is `2 + 3 = 5`.

What you now want to do is not add up the digits themselves, but their factorial, so you could call your factorial function with the remainder as argument, and add that to the tail calculation rather than just the digit itself.

Note that for larger numbers this becomes a bit computation intensive. You can use a technique called 'memoization' to remember (or pre-calculate) the factorials you need. After all, you only use the factorials of 0 - 9. You could pre-calculate those and store them in an array to optimze your code. I am expecting this to be next in this obviously homework assignment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement another function invoking `factorial` for separate digits:

```java
public static int sum_of_digit_factorial(int n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return factorial(n);
    }
    return factorial(n % 10) + sum_of_digit_factorial(n / 10);
}
```